# Como deixar valores já preenchidos no input (VUE Js)

Tags: html, node.js, vue.js

Estou fazendo um CRUD simples, com Vue, Node, MariaDB.
Na parte de update, não sei como pegar os valores do usuário e já deixar preenchido. (Sou iniciante)

```
            <div>
              <p>Nome</p>
              <input type="input">
              <p>Data de nascimento</p>
              <input type="input">
              <p>Email</p>
              <input type="input">
              <h2 class = "endereco">Seu endereço</h2>
              <p>Rua</p>
              <input type="input"> 
              <p>Número</p>
              <input type="input">
              <p>Bairro</p>
              <input type="input">
              <button class="btnAdd" @click="addUser()">Atualizar</button>
             </div>
```

Os dados de usuarios estao em uma tabela, cada linha tem o botao de editar.
Como faço para preencher os campos do usuário no input?

Comment: De uma olhada na documentação ela é bem fácil, https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html a grosso modo você vai preencher o valor usando o v-model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para preencher o valor deve utilizar [v-model](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html) para `<form/>` da seguinte forma crie um modelo (`model`) e agrupe os seus valores, depois em cada `input` escreve o campo referente ao modelo e a sua chave respectiva, como demonstrada logo abaixo:

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#editor',
  data: {
    model: {
      nome: 'nome',
      nascimento: '01/01/1999',
      email: 'p@p.com',
      rua: 'rua',
      numero: '1',
      bairro: 'Bairro'
    }
  },
  methods: {
      addUser: function() {
        console.log('clicado');
      }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="editor">
<div>
    <p>Nome</p>
    <input type="text" v-model="model.nome">
    <p>Data de nascimento</p>
    <input type="text" v-model="model.nascimento">
    <p>Email</p>
    <input type="text" v-model="model.email">
    <h2 class = "endereco">Seu endereço</h2>
    <p>Rua</p>
    <input type="text" v-model="model.rua"> 
    <p>Número</p>
    <input type="text" v-model="model.numero">
    <p>Bairro</p>
    <input type="text" v-model="model.bairro">
    <button class="btnAdd" @click="addUser()">Atualizar</button>
   </div> 
</div>
```

<sup>***Observação:*** encontrei alguns erros no seu `html`, verifique no exemplo as diferenças</sup>